# Kivy and Python creating a slideshow that Moves when gets clicked

Tags: user-interface, kivy

I am having trouble with making a picture slideshow that is operated with python and executed with kivy.

I am using asynch but I want to make the slideshow so that I open the photo and then when I click with the right it goes forward, but then if the mouse gets clicked on the left, then it goes to the previous page (picture).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the comment# from the buttons and move left/right methods if you want but I think the carousel direction feature solves that problem. Mind you, I am a newbie so this is just my way of helping out. I figured I'll help some else since I have gotten a lot of help here. Thanks

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.loader import Loader
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    carousel: carousel
    cols: 1
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.1}
        size_hint: .3,.1
        font_size: 35
        text: str(root.on_off)
        on_release: root.start_slide()
    Carousel:
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.9}
        id: carousel
        direction: 'right'
        loop: True
        index: 0
''')

class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    on_off = StringProperty('Start')
    slide_count = NumericProperty(11)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.carousel = Carousel(direction='right')
        self.add_widget(self.carousel)
        for i in range(self.slide_count):
            src = "http://placehold.it/480x270.png&text=slide-%d&.png" % i
            image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            self.carousel.add_widget(image)
        #self.start_slide()### Uncomment this to start slideshow when the app starts

    def start_slide(self, *args):
        if self.on_off == 'Start':
            self.on_off = 'Stop'
            self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.slide_next, 3) ##move right every 3 seconds
            return
        if self.on_off == 'Stop':
            self.on_off = 'Start'
            Clock.unschedule(self.clock)
            self.carousel.index = 0

    def slide_next(self, *args):
        if self.carousel.index == (self.slide_count - 1):
            self.carousel.index = 0### This keeps the loops intact
            #### if you want to end the slideshow at the last image, use 'Clock.unschedule(self.clock)' instead
            return
        self.carousel.load_next()

class SlideShowApp(App):

    def build(self):
        mywidget = MyWidget()
        return mywidget

if __name__ == '__main__':

    SlideShowApp().run()
```

Hope this is what you needed